# std::map help in image handler class

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I am writing an imagehandler for an engine. So far it's going pretty good (I think) but I need help with deleting images.  I have experience with `vector`s but not with `map`s.

The image handler has an std::map which has 2 elements:

```
std::map<std::string, SDL_Surface*> image_list_;
std::map<std::string, SDL_Surface*>::iterator it;
```

Then i have 2 methods in my ImageHandler class:

```
void AddImage(std::string/*file_name*/);
void DeleteImage(std::string/*file_name*/);
```

Here are the guts of these 2 methods:

```
bool ImageHandler::AddImage(std::string file_name)
{
    SDL_Surface* temp = NULL;
    if ((temp = Image::Load(file_name)) == NULL)
        return false;
    image_list_.insert(std::pair<std::string, SDL_Surface*>(file_name, temp));
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
    return true;
}

bool ImageHandler::DeleteImage(std::string file_name)
{
    if (image_list_.empty()) return;
    it = image_list_.find(file_name);
    if (!it) return false;
    image_list_.erase(it);
    return true;
}
```

I haven't compiled this code so I am not aware of any syntax errors. If any exist you can just look past those.

I think my `DeleteImage` method  will remove it from the `map` but to avoid memory leaks when it loads an image I need to do this:

```
SDL_FreeSurface(SDL_Surface*);
```

So I think I need to access an iterator's *second* element at a specific map index. Am I doing it right so far and how would I be able to do this?

Comment: SDL_FreeSurface(it->second); image_list_.erase(it);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
bool ImageHandler::DeleteImage(std::string const & file_name)
{
  if ((it = image_list_.find(file_name)) == image_list_.end())
  {
    return false;
  }

  SDL_FreeSurface(it->second);
  image_list_.erase(it);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: i have a question how would i get the second element of a map at an index like the_map_[0].second?

Comment: @sikesusmc: I don't understand the question. Maps have no "index", rather, they have "keys". And `m["hello"]` is already the *mapped value* of the entry with key `"hello"`. (Alternatively, `m.find("hello")->second`, assuming the element exists.)

Comment: oh.  how would i get the second element of a map just with a number?  like an array or something.  dont maps use the [] operator

Comment: @sikesusmc: They do, but for key lookup. Maps *do not have indices*. Maps are not sequence containers. You have to iterate the map and count if you really must have numeric access, but you have to understand that that gives you the elements in their key order, not in insertion order.

Comment: @sikes oorah - I'd consider a `vector` of `set`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, you would do

```
SDL_FreeSurface(it->second);
```

**before** you erase it from the map.

That would make the function:

```
bool ImageHandler::DeleteImage(std::string file_name)
{
    if (image_list_.empty()) return;
    it = image_list_.find(file_name);
    if (!it) return false;
    SDL_FreeSurface(it->second);
    image_list_.erase(it);
    return true;
}
```